# TYPO3 11 call stdWrap from Extbase

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-11.x

How do you call the *ContentObjectRenderer* method **stdWrap** from Extbase?

The setup from a pi_base plugin is:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    standard = TEXT
    standard.value = Sorry, no data could be fetched!
}
```

In TYPO3 extensions without Extbase you have the `$conf` array with the keys

```
'standard' =>
     'TEXT' (string)
```

and the key

```
 'standard.' => 
      'value' (array) =>
          'Sorry, no data could be fetched!'.
```

Then you call the method by:

```
$out =
    $cObj->stdWrap(
        $conf['standard'],
        $conf['standard.']
    );
```

This will render the desired text 'Sorry, no data could be fetched!' into `$out`.

But in Extbase you do not have the $conf array in this way. Exbase delivers the `$this->settings` to store the settings part of the setup.

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    settings {
        standard = TEXT
        standard.value = Sorry, no data could be fetched!
    }
}
```

The standard setup is internally stored by Extbase as a 2-dimensional array with this data:

```
'standard' 
   => 'value' (Array) 
       => 'Sorry, no data could be fetched!'
```

and

```
'standard' 
   => '_typoScriptNodeValue' (Array) 
       => 'TEXT'
```

I have tried it this way (`$conf = $this->settings`):

```
$out =
    $cObj->stdWrap(
        '',
        $conf['standard']
    );
```

And I have tried this:

```
$out =
    $cObj->stdWrap(
        $conf['standard']['_typoScriptNodeValue'],
        $conf['standard']
    );
```

But the result is an empty string only.

What is the recommended way to accomplish the stdWrap rendering with Extbase?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a look into the News extension can help. IMO it's a proper, flexible way without much overhead.

```
    // Use stdWrap for given defined settings

    if (isset($originalSettings['useStdWrap']) && !empty($originalSettings['useStdWrap'])) {
        $typoScriptService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScriptService::class);
        $typoScriptArray = $typoScriptService->convertPlainArrayToTypoScriptArray($originalSettings);
        $stdWrapProperties = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $originalSettings['useStdWrap'], true);
        foreach ($stdWrapProperties as $key) {
            if (is_array($typoScriptArray[$key . '.'])) {
                $originalSettings[$key] = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->stdWrap(
                    $typoScriptArray[$key],
                    $typoScriptArray[$key . '.']
                );
            }
        }
    }

    // start override
    if (isset($tsSettings['settings']['overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty'])) {
        $typoScriptUtility = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScript::class);
        $originalSettings = $typoScriptUtility->override($originalSettings, $tsSettings);
    }

    // ...

    $this->settings = $originalSettings;
```

snippet taken from https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/main/Classes/Controller/NewsController.php#L658-L688

Answer (score 1):

Basically `$cObj->stdWrap` only supports [`stdWrap`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html) instructions - however, you were using a [`cObject` instruction (with `TEXT`)](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Index.html).

##### Let's assume your `settings` look like this in TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    settings {
        standard {
          # cObject is a stdWrap function
          # (that was the missing piece)
          cObject = TEXT
          cObject.value = Sorry, no data could be fetched!
        }
    }
}
```

---

Inside an Extbase controller `$this->settings` holds all data of the TypoScript path `plugin.tx_myextension.settings` as shown in the example before - and, the structure has been converted to be a "plain array".

##### Thus, inside a controller action things would look like this:

```
public function myAction()
{
    // consider using dependency-injection instead
    $typoScriptService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\TypoScriptService::class);
    // converting "plain array" back to TypoScript array
    $typoScriptArray = $typoScriptService->convertPlainArrayToTypoScriptArray($this->settings['standard']);

    // invoking stdWrap instruction    
    $cObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
    $out = $cObj->stdWrap('', $typoScriptArray);
    // ...
}
```

---

##### Additional considerations:

- in Extbase, plugin settings from TypoScript and potential FlexForm settings for a specific plugin are merged

  - → make sure, to keep scopes separated before "executing" it as instruction
  - → otherwise editors might be able to trigger `stdWrap` functions via FlexForm
  - → **that would be an "injection" and a security vulnerability**
- e.g. use `plugin.tx_myextension.instructions` dedicated to be used in e.g. `stdWrap`, instead of putting everything to `plugin.tx_myextension.settings`
- in general consider moving view-related aspects to a corresponding view or Fluid template, e.g using [`f:cObject` view helper](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html) there

Comment: Does this mean that the setup should have a naming scheme like `plugin.tx_myextension.instructions.standard` for security reasons? But then I will not be able to read the value for the "standard" setup from the `$this->settings` variable. How would I get the value for "instructions.standard" into a local variable of the Controller class?

Comment: `plugin.tx_myextension.instructions.standard` probably would be used e.g. `f:cObject` view helper. In case you need everything in a controller, just make sure there are no side-effects from FlexForm or similar.

Comment: When the `$this->settings` variable cannot be used, then the setup must be read in the Controller class by `injectConfigurationManager` and `$tsSettings = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration` .

Comment: It does not work.
`$typoScriptArray = $typoScriptService->convertPlainArrayToTypoScriptArray($this->settings['standard']); ` .
This line does nothing. `$this->settings['standard']` is still the same after the conversion: `$typoScriptArray`.

Comment: It works in this way:
`$typoScriptArray = ['cObject' => $conf['standard'], 'cObject.' => $conf['standard.']];
$out = $cObj->stdWrap($message, $typoScriptArray);`

Is it necessary to add `cObject` and `cObject.` as keys to the array of the `stdWrap` parameter?

Comment: Could you modify your proposal? Then it would also be a working solution.